# Incorrect filling of sqlite database from xml file

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

friends!

Please help me to solve my problem. I`m trying to fill sqlite database from xml, receive 0 errors but the values in database are confused.

Here is an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cards>
    <record
        path="R.mipmap.ot1"
        man="man1"
        woman="woman1" />
    <record
        path="R.mipmap.ot2"
        man="man2"
        woman="woman2" />
</cards>
```

Here is DBhelper class. The method onUpgrade is empty, but atm I clear application data manually every time.

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
        String sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, path TEXT, man TEXT, woman TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sqlStatement);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

Here comes the part of importing data from xml to database

```
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("mytable", null, null);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.cardslist);
    try {

        int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {                    
                String path = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
                String man = _xml.getAttributeValue(1);
                String woman = _xml.getAttributeValue(2);

                values.put("path", path);
                values.put("man", man);
                values.put("woman", woman);

                db.insert("mytable", null, values);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
            }
            eventType = _xml.next();
        }
    }
    // Catch errors
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
        // Close the xml file
        _xml.close();
    }

    dbHelper.close();
```

So i want to receive

```
path = R.mipmap.ot1 man = man1 woman = woman1
       R.mipmap.ot2       man2         woman2
```

but receive

```
path=man1 man=R.mipmap.ot1 woman=woman1
     man2     R.mipmap.ot2       woman2
```

Please, help me to solve this problem.
Many thanks.

Comment: I think in your XML man is at index 1 and not 2?

Comment: Sorry, have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved, the reason was that XmlPullParser parses data from xml in alphabet order. So i just renamed path to apath.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `ContentValues` declaration inside the loop:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {                    
        String path = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
        String man = _xml.getAttributeValue(1);
        String woman = _xml.getAttributeValue(2);

        values.put("path", path);
        values.put("man", man);
        values.put("woman", woman);

        db.insert("mytable", null, values);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
    }
    eventType = _xml.next();
}
```

Or you can use `values.clear()` at the start of each iteration, I think it may be better than declaring new `ContentValues` object.

Comment: Thank you for help, but in didn`t work out. Still the same issue

Comment: @Sopelus Can you check that you are getting the correct values from XML, by Loggin the for example? `Log.d(TAG, "path " + path)`

Comment: Sure, the issue comes from xml, but i can`t understand why

 D/ContentValues: path man1
D/ContentValues: man R.mipmap.ot1
D/ContentValues: woman woman1

D/ContentValues: path man2
D/ContentValues: man R.mipmap.ot2
D/ContentValues: woman woman2

Comment: Thank you, friend, you too :)